# Error when passing args of main into a class method

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am in fact a beginner in Python (I use C and Java though). I was given [this](http://www.control.lth.se/media/Education/DoctorateProgram/IntroToCloudComputing/clos_topo.py) python script that is supposed to be fine and has no bugs.

```
def setup_clos_topo(fanout=2, cores=1):
    "Create and test a simple clos network"
    assert(fanout>0)
    # ...


def main(argv):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Parse input information for mininet Clos network")
    parser.add_argument('--num_of_core_switches', '-c', dest='cores', type=int, help='number of core switches')
    parser.add_argument('--fanout', '-f', dest='fanout', type=int, help='network fanout')
    args = parser.parse_args(argv)
    setLogLevel('info')
    setup_clos_topo(args.fanout, args.cores)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

When running the script(i.e. sudo ./clos_topo.py ), I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./clos_topo.py", line 107, in <module>
    main(sys.argv[1:])
  File "./clos_topo.py", line 103, in main
    setup_clos_topo(args.fanout, args.cores)
  File "./clos_topo.py", line 85, in setup_clos_topo
    assert(fanout>0)
AssertionError
```

Can someone tell why this error occurs? Thank you

Comment: `fanout` appears to be required to be greater than zero but it defaults to zero if not set.  By deleting `sys.argv[1:]` you are preventing all of the arguments from being parsed.

Comment: I added the `ct_n` in above code. fanout is greater than zero!!

Comment: That's a default value if none is provided when `ct_n()` is invoked.  It's not an assignment.  `args.fanout` is specified as zero when `sys.argv[1:]` does not get passed.

Comment: What do you mean by "When _compiling_ the script"? Python scripts aren't compiled. What command are you running to "compile" the script? Your code works exactly as I would expect when I run it from the command line. If I give it no arguments I get the assert as expected, and with arguments such as `--fanout 3` I get no assertion.

Comment: I meant when running the script as `sudo ./clos_topo.py` .. I apologize but I work with java and C where compiling word comes frequently in context! I have modified my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is behaving correctly, there are no bugs.

Since you didn't specify otherwise, the default value for `fanout` is `None`. Since you aren't using the `--fanout` argument on the command line, `None` is being passed to `setup_clos_topo`, and since `None` is not greater than zero, you get the assertion failure.

If you want the default to be something other than zero, you must specify it when defining the argument:

```
parser.add_argument('--fanout', ..., default=2)
```

---

Note: if you have a default parameter in a function (eg: `def foo(x=2)`) and  you pass in a parameter (eg: `foo(x)`), the value passed in will always override the default. It does not matter if the value you're passing in is `None` or not, it will always override the default value.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Appreciate it. I am required to pass these argument via CLI but I don't know how. I tried several ways like `sudo ./clos_topo.py --fanout 3 --cores 2` but nothing work. It is not clear to me how to pass argument via CLI based on the given script

Comment: @JeffryHods: what you wrote is exactly how you do it: `./clos_topo.py --fanout 3 --cores 2`